# how write the result of vlookup pandas in a new csv file

Tags: python, pandas, vlookup

i try to write the result of a vlookup from an excel in a column of a second excel so i extract the series with this code, and it' work.

for exemple i've got in a first excel

```
a    b    
1    10   
5    17   
1    19
```

i want to extract the column b when the column a = 1
so i use :

```
df5 = pd.read_excel(r'Y:\SIG-DROPBOX\3_Centre_de_Ressources\METADONNEES\SuiviGlobalMetadonnees.xlsm', None)
print ("df5")
print (df5.keys())
for feuille in df5:
    df1 = pd.read_excel(r'Y:\SIG-DROPBOX\3_Centre_de_Ressources\METADONNEES\SuiviGlobalMetadonnees.xlsm', feuille)
    # Notre fonction
    df3 = df1[df1["valide"]=="oui"]
    dada="Tables dans "+feuille+" (bases de données sde)"
    print (dada)
    df4 = df3[dada]
    print('df4')
    print (df4)
```

and so my script extract for the exemple:

```
b
10
19
```

now i want to put the result of my extract of an another excel with an existing column.
for exemple:

```
aa  bb  cc  
    10
    19
```

but when i try to write the result of df4 with tis code:

```
df6 = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\data\remplissage.xls')
print('df6')
print (df6)
df4.to_excel(df6,'Nom_Mapservice')
```

nothing happens

can you help me to resolve my problem?

---

Hi everybody!
so i go forward with my script so i change the end to append the extract of my series (after df4)in a column of an  another xls.
so i write my script like this:

```html
    listing = pd.Series(df4)
    print('listing')
    print (listing)

    df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\data\remplissage.xls',None)
    print (df)
    for feuille2 in df:
        print (feuille2)
        df6 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\data\remplissage.xls', feuille2)
        print (df6)
        df7 = df6['Tables dans DEV (bases de données sde)'].append(df4, ignore_index = True)
        print("df7")
        print (df7)
```

but nothing is happening
i don't hav an error and nothing append in the excel.

can you help me to solve that please

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Share sample data and expected output

Comment: ok i hope it's better now ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this: df.to_excel('file_name.xlsx'), where df is the dataframe you want to write into excel and file_name is the name of the excel file you want to store in.

Comment: Please properly formats the code that you use in your answers so it can be more readable for other users.

Comment: yes i'ts work if i want to create a new xls but i want to increment my result in a column of an exisitng excel